# How to connect iPhone to external monitor via HDMI with mouse support?

Tags: iphone, bluetooth, mouse, screen, hdmi

**The problem**

I have an iPhone 8 with a busted touch-screen. Specifically, everything visible on the screen is upside down and moving/shaking, and not all parts of the screen are sensitive to physical touch. Using a [Lightning-to-HDMI adapter](https://www.bestbuy.com/site/apple-lightning-digital-a-v-adapter-white/7007013.p?skuId=7007013&ref=212&loc=1&extStoreId=1180&ref=212&loc=1&gclsrc=ds), I can project the screen of my iPhone onto an external monitor just fine. But because the touch-screen is busted, I would like to use a mouse to scroll and click about. Is there a way to do this?

**What I've tried**

After verifying that the phone still "works" over HDMI, I got [another adapter](https://www.bestbuy.com/site/apple-usb-type-c-digital-av-multiport-adapter-white/5596800.p?skuId=5596800&ref=212&loc=1&extStoreId=1180&ref=212&loc=1&gclsrc=ds) with an additional USB slot so that I can plug in my mouse. I would need a female USB-C to male USB-A adapter to try this approach; however, both Geek Squad and Apple techs tell me that this method will not work.

The Apple techs suggested buying a blue-tooth mouse for under $10 online, but Geek Squad tells me this method will not work unless I buy an Apple dongle and connect to an Apple TV (which I don't own).